# Nextjs 12 Error When Running on Cloud Run But Works Well on Localhost

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to upgrade from nextjs v10 to v12. It successfully worked at localhost, but when deployed on cloud run and running on the active domain, it shows 500 Internal Server Error. Previously it worked well on cloud run with nextjs v10.

I create a test page to check what makes it error and after testing, it may seems the 'getServerSideProps' is the problem.

Here is my code, /pages/test2.js

```
import Layout from 'components/layout'

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    return {
        props: {
            data: { title: 'test' },
        },
    }
}
export default function Test({ data }) {
    console.log('testtt', data)
    return (
        <Layout activeId="home">
            <div>ABC TEsT</div>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

If I remove 'getServerSideProps' function then deploy to cloud run, then the page is working well.

Here is the error found on cloud run server log

> SyntaxError : Unexpected token '.'

[Link to error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5mO3.jpg)

The weird thing is, there is no error on localhost.

Is there any problem with getServerSideProps on nextjs v12 or I am missing configuration?
I have no custom webpack and babel config.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste your actual code **between backticks** (w/the nullish coelescing operator you're using) and paste the full statcktrace in plaintext from Cloud Run (I've found that Cloud Logging is the easiest place to do this within the console). This will help us help you!

Comment: What Node.js version are you using on Cloud Run server?